# SWIFT string with special characters without escape

Tags: ios, swift

How to print all special characters without inserting escape sign before every of them? I have very large textiles with many special characters and I'm looking for something like @ in c# which prints string literally as it is

Comment: You need to update your question with relevant code as well as sample input, undesired output, and desired output.

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to, is called a **verbatim string literal** in C# and that concept does not translate exactly to Swift.

However, with the introduction of *multiline string Literals* in Swift 4, you can get close.

```
let multilineString = """
    Here you can use \ and newline characters.
    Also single " or double "" are allowed.
"""
```

For reference, find the grammar of a Swift String literal [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html).

Comment: There's an accepted proposal [SE-0200](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md) that allows for single-line raw string `#"c:\windows\system32"#`. I don't know when it is available, just that it's NOT in Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10).

Comment: @fguchelaar I'm getting "Invalid escape sequence in literal" in Xcode 10 if I don't escape the backslash (\\).